# How to cast a WebControl from a GridViewRow

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have some `GridView` with a changing amount of Columns. Just the last column is always the same, but they don't have the same name.

```
<asp:GridView>
    <%-- columns are here--%>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton>
            </asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</asp:GridView>
```

Now I loop trough my page to disable all the controls on a specific status:

```
public static void disableControls(ContentPlaceHolder cph)
{

    foreach (Control c in cph.Controls)
    {
        disableControl(c);
        foreach (Control c2 in c.Controls)
        {
    //and so on, this goes until 20 controls deep
        }
    }
}
```

and in my `disableControl()` I check for all types (`TextBox`, `Button` etc) and then I disable them. The onliest exception are the `GridView`s. Because if I disable them they aren't scrollable anymore. So i tried to keep the `GridView`s enabled and just loop through the rows and try to cast every cell to a `LinkButton` to disable it. Because somehow they don't get disabled trough my normal loop with all the controls and its childcontrols. But this also doesn't work, because they never get casted. What I tried till now (and didn't work):

**Try 1:**

```
foreach (GridViewRow gvr in gv.Rows)
{
    if (gvr.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < gv.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton lb = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton)gvr.Cells[i].Controls[0];
                lb.Enabled = false;
             }
             catch(Exception)
             {}              
        }
    }
}
```

**Try 2:**

```
foreach (GridViewRow gvr in gv.Rows)
{
    foreach (TableCell cell in gvr.Cells)
    {
        foreach (Control con in cell.Controls)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton lb = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton)con;
                lb.Enabled = false;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            { }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I make sure that the `LinkButton`s in the `GridView`s get disabled, but the `GridView` itself not?

Btw: What came to my mind after writing all this long text: Is it possible that "Parent"-Controls(The GridViews) `Enabled`-Status overwrites the "Child"-Controls-Enabled-Status?!

Comment: Answer to your last question: yes, afaik they inherit this property, similar to `Visible`. That makes sense, on this way you can _disable_ a `Panel` which disables also all controls in this panel. But that applies only to `Enabled = false`. This is also documented: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.enabled(v=vs.100).aspx _"This property propagates down the control hierarchy. If you disable a container control, the child controls within that container are also disabled..."_

Comment: @TimSchmelter Puh. So there is no way to enable the GridView and disable some parts of the Rows ? And yeah, if you already mention the `Panel`: I had everything in a `Panel` before, and it disabled all controls in it, but so the GridView wasn't scrollable anymore. So there is nothing left except extending the GridView?
Edit: Ah okay, so this shouldn't be the problem in my case. Thanks alot!

Comment: Also, don't use `try/catch` to try-cast to a type, the `as`-operator was made for  this reason: `var lb = con as LinkButton; if(lb!=null)lb.Enabled=false;`

Comment: Thanks! I will keep that in mind and change it in my code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went around it with manually disabling all controls (looping through the panel-children & its children etc, recursively) of the panels

Somehow the "scrollable"-function doesn't gets lost if you set all WebControls by hand to disabled, if you set only the Panel to disabled it gets inherited and the "scrollable"-function of the GridView gets lost.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is your check assumes it's a linkbutton, but you type check the control first:

```
if (lb is System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton)
{
    ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton)con).Enabled = false
}
```

You can also type check on WebControl, and disable all web controls that way too.

Comment: Well as mentioned, I don't want to disable ALL. Only nearly all, except the `GridViews`. Sadly the `LinkButtons` are still not disabled. And yes, usually I type check like in your code, but it didn't work this time, so I tried it with try/catch. Both things don't work.